# How can I cast a value into two bytes in Dafny?

Tags: dafny

I want to convert an integer from 0 to 65355 and for that I need a two byte representation. I'm trying to divide it by 2, 8 times, and sum the powers of 2 when the rest is one, and then cast that integer as a byte but I'm having problems meeting the restrictions of a byte (256). The second byte will be the rest of the 8th division and I'm having problems casting that as a byte too.

The following is my code for the previously described function method:

```
method convertBin(i:int) returns (b:seq<byte>)
requires 0<=i<=65535;
{
  var b1:=0;
  var q:=i;
  var j:=0;
  while j<8
    invariant 0<=j<=8 && (b1 as int)< power(2,j)
    decreases 8-j
  {
    var p:int;
    if(q%2==1){
      p:=power(2, j);
      b1:=b1 + p;
      q:=q/2;
    }
    j:=j+1;
  }
  b1:=b1 as byte;
  b:=[b1]+[q as byte];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete your example, you need stronger loop invariants. But you don't need a loop at all, since there's no reason to divide only by 2.

Here's doing it with `byte` as a subset type:

```
type byte = x | 0 <= x < 256

method convertBin(i: int) returns (b1: byte, b0: byte)
  requires 0 <= i < 0x1_0000
  ensures i == 256 * b1 + b0
{
  b1, b0 := i / 256, i % 256;
}
```

And here's the same program, but with `byte` being a `newtype`:

```
newtype byte = x | 0 <= x < 256

method convertBin(i: int) returns (b1: byte, b0: byte)
  requires 0 <= i < 0x1_0000
  ensures i == 256 * b1 as int + b0 as int
{
  b1, b0 := (i / 256) as byte, (i % 256) as byte;
}
```

Rustan

Comment: Thank you, Rustan! I was overcomplicating the whole thing.